# C# - Should I use Substring to Get 2nd value in a single csv row?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ssis, substring

How can I use C# to return the 2nd value in the below comma separated values row?

> "ABC",3/31/2016 0:00:00,"0020","1003802877","5.89",1

I already have the above string loaded into a variable in SSIS. I used C# to load the single row into the variable.

Would it be easier to just use a substring function on the string since I already have it available in the variable or should I use some other function(s) to parse the csv row and then return only the 2nd value (3/31/2016 0:00:00)?

Comment: There is the string.Split method that could transform your string in an array

Comment: string[] array =  string.Split(',');

Comment: If the first column can contain values that can have commas, then you'll need to do special parsing to ignore commas inside of double quotes.  Otherwise `Substring` and `IndexOf` to find the first and second comma will work, or `string.Split`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [string.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string input = "\"ABC\",3/31/2016 0:00:00,\"0020\",\"1003802877\",\"5.89\",1";
string[] parts = input.Split(',');
Console.WriteLine(parts[1]);
```

Note that to show you this example I have added the escape character before the double quotes. These escapes are not necessary (and are not present) if your input string comes from the CSV file

Using string.IndexOf and string.Substring is also possible but really too much complicated against the simple string.Split

```
int pos = input.IndexOf(',');
if (pos > 0)
{
    int pos2 = input.IndexOf(',', pos+1);
    if(pos2 < 0) pos2 = input.Length;
    Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(pos+1, pos2 - (pos+1)));
}
```

Comment: you can also try this: `string str = "\"ABC\",3/31/2016 0:00:00,\"0020\",\"1003802877\",\"5.89\",1";
            string res = str.Split(',')[1];
            Console.WriteLine(res);` _(input string as already shown by @Steve)_

Answer (score 1):

Does Performance matter in your case ? Do you have very large strings ? Are you executing this logic in a loop ?

Split is really fast, but it has to traverse the whole string. `IndexOf` (with Substring) just stops at the first occurrence. So if you're doing this operation in a loop and cutting off more than half of the time matters for you, then use `Substring` and `IndexOf` :

```
int indexStart = csv.IndexOf(',');
int indexEnd = indexStart < 0 ? 0 : csv.IndexOf(',', indexStart + 1);

string result = null;

if(indexEnd > 0)
    result = csv.Substring(indexStart + 1, indexEnd - indexStart - 1);
```

Comment: No, just a simple 1 time check of the first row of the file to grab the 2nd value but thanks for sharing this method as I am sure it will come in handy soon.